# Usar firebase job dispatcher o PowerManager wakelock

Tags: android-studio, backgroundworker

Tengo una aplicación móvil en la que obtengo la localización cada 5 minutos, en el momento estoy utilizando PowerManager wakelock y funciona bien cuando bloqueo el equipo, pero cuando cierro la apliacion deja de funcionar, lo que necesito es que la aplicación siga tomando la localizacion en backgroud, alguien tiene puede recomendarme si sigo trabajando con PowerManager wakelock o necesito cambiar?

Answer (score 0):

pues yo uso firebase para obtener las pociciones en tiempo real y funcionan, cada vez que abro la app me da la posición actual y la ultima posición de cuando cerre la app, es decir cierro la app y esa es la ultima posición y cuando abro me muestra la ultima y en donde esta en tiempo real eso lo hago con firebase, si lo que quieres es que siga ejecutándose luego de cerrar la app lo que debes es hacer un servicio y pues si quieres agregarle una notificación de que la posición de esa persona ha cambiado para que el usuario entre por medio de la notificación a la app, igual también se puede hacer con firebase yo hago todo esto y la posición es cada 1seg

Espero haberte ayudado, y a la próxima se mas explicito o pon algo de código para poder ver a que te refieres con claridad, que tengas buen día o noche xD